# Округление чисел .5 в JS

Tags: javascript, html5

При вычислении в JS получаю ответ например 12.5, если указываю , чтобы показывало только целую часть, выдаёт 12, а должно 13.

Comment: стоит добавить код, который используется

Comment: _если указываю , чтобы показывало только целую часть_ - как ни странно. но целая часть от 12.5 это именно 12. Таким образом, что указал, то и получил

Comment: Действительно, спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: @Grundy есть несколько вариантов : https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#.D0.92.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.82.D1.8B_.D0.BE.D0.BA.D1.80.D1.83.D0.B3.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_0.2C5_.D0.BA_.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B6.D0.B0.D0.B9.D1.88.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.83_.D1.86.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.BC.D1.83

Comment: @C.Raf.T, в вопросе нет ничего про _округление_, там есть про _показывание целой части_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Math.ceil** - всегда округляет в большую сторону.
- **Math.round** - округляет по целой части.
- **Math.floor** - всегда в меньшую сторону.

```js
let a = .5;
let b = .4;

console.log( Math.ceil( a ), Math.ceil( b ) ); // 1 1
console.log( Math.round( a ), Math.round( b ) ); // 1 0
console.log( Math.floor( a ), Math.floor( b ) ); // 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = 1.5;
console.log(x.toFixed())
```